# Change (reset) appearance of mail compose window

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

Since a recent (August 2019) automatic Outlook Office update the fields at the top of the edit window have become really unintuitive. The subject field now has very little attention (grey, no border):

[image]

Over the past two weeks I *keep* putting the subject behind the CC: button.
Luckily, the mail won't go out then.
I have heard the same from colleagues.

Is there *any* way to revert the changes to the compose window, or change it's appearance?
We do need the CC: field.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, there's no method to customize it.